# Как продолжить выполнение кода после "выброса" exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться
Есть следующий код и проблема заключается в том, что если `URL`-адреса (передаваемого в качестве `request`) не существует или он в данный момент не отвечает, то программа выкидывает `Exception` и на этом заканчивает работа, а мне необходимо, чтобы работа продолжалась, т.е. `Exception` появлился, в `Logger` записался, но работа продолжилась в обычном режиме, как так можно сделать?

```
public async Task<AuctionRequest> ProcessBidRequest(BidRequestModel requestModel, string endpoint, string protocol)
        {
            try
            {
                var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel);

                using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpoint);
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }
                request.Headers.Add("x-openrtb-version", protocol);

                using var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    throw new BadResponseException(response.ReasonPhrase);

                var respString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (respString.Length == 0)
                    throw new ArgumentException("The response is empty string.");

                return new AuctionRequest(requestModel, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BidResponseModel>(respString), protocol);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Сам метод вызвается при переборе массива, вот часть кода, которая отвечает за вызов данного метода

```
int k = 0;
foreach (var advert in rtb_partners)
{
    string[] address = { //Список URL-адресов };
    bids[i++] = ProcessBidRequest(bidRequest, address[k++], protocolVersion);
}
```

Comment: Ну так поймайте его, исключение-то ваше...

Comment: А могли бы Вы поподробнее описать
просто я его и так ловлю, но на этом выполнение программы завершается, а мне необходимо продолжить работу, до тех пор пока в массиве `address` есть значения

Comment: ловить-то вы его ловите, да только кидаете дальше

Comment: Если Вы иммету ввиду, что необходимо удалить `throw ex`, то я пробовал, ошибка, так как тогда метод не возращает объект `AuctionRequest`

Comment: Могли бы Вы подробнее описать, что необходимо исправить?

Comment: Ну ловите исключение снова в точке вызова, делов-то. Не забудьте сначала получить AuctionRequest или исключение, и лишь потом, если нужно, увеличить `i`

Comment: Понятнее не стало, могли бы Вы написать пример кода, что именно мне надо изменить? Просто пока у меня все сделано так как Вы и говорите

Comment: @Nikita начните с вот этого кода: `try { bids[i++] = ProcessBidRequest(bidRequest, address[k++], protocolVersion); } catch (Exception ex) { ... }`

Answer (score -1):

```
public async Task<AuctionRequest> ProcessBidRequest(BidRequestModel requestModel, string endpoint, string protocol)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        return new AuctionRequest
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning(ex.Message);
        //throw ex;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не скомпилируется.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]