# Как продолжить выполнение кода после выброса Exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

В дополнении к моему вопросу ([https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1300872/Как-продолжить-выполнение-кода-после-выброса-exception?noredirect=1#comment2295259_1300872](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1300872/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-exception?noredirect=1#comment2295259_1300872)), я поправил код, добавил `try/catch` в цикле, но при получении Ecxpetion программа завершает свою работу, подскажите пожалуйста, как избежать завершения работы программы, после выброса `Exception`?

Исправленный код:

```
public async Task<AuctionRequest[]> GetBids(ICollection<RtbModel> rtb_partners, AuctionModel auctionModel)
        {
            var bids = new Task<AuctionRequest>[rtb_partners.Count];
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            int k = 0;

            string[] address = { @"http://192.168.56.1:8000/response.json", @"http://192.168.56.1:8000/response4.json", @"http://192.168.56.1:8000/response3.json" };

            foreach (var advert in rtb_partners)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (advert == null)
                        throw new Exception("Dsp not found");

                    var protocol = advert.Protocol;
                    string protocolVersion = protocol switch
                    {
                        RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_2 => "2.2",
                        RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_3 => "2.3",
                        RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_4 => "2.4",
                        RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_5 => "2.5",
                        _ => throw new NotSupportedException("RTB protocol not supported")
                    };
                    var settings = new RTBSettingsModel(advert.ProtocolOptions);

                    var bidRequest = BuildBidRequestModel(auctionModel[j++], settings);

                    bids[i] = ProcessBidRequest(bidRequest, address[k], protocolVersion);

                    i++;
                    k++;

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning(e.Message);
                }
            }

            return await Task.WhenAll(bids);
        }


public async Task<AuctionRequest> ProcessBidRequest(BidRequestModel requestModel, string endpoint, string protocol)
        {
            try
            {
                var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel);

                using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpoint);
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }
                request.Headers.Add("x-openrtb-version", protocol);

                using var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    throw new BadResponseException(response.ReasonPhrase);

                var respString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (respString.Length == 0)
                    throw new ArgumentException("The response is empty string.");

                return new AuctionRequest(requestModel, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BidResponseModel>(respString), protocol);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: У Вас исключение выбрасывает при запуске из Visual Studio? Если да, то там можно просто нажать продолжить, после публикации приложения вылетов при исключениях не будет.

Comment: Исключение выбрасывается при компиляции, у меня нет варианта с "продолжить"

Comment: То есть компиляция полностью завершается и напротив "Зеленого треугольника"  в студии нет надписи "Продолжить"? Извините, что общаюсь как с незнающим, просто часто встречал данную проблему и многие на ней тупят.

Comment: В какой строке у вас `Exception` бросается?

Comment: return await Task.WhenAll(bids);

Comment: Перехват исключений внутри Task'ов тот ещё геморрой.

Comment: Оберните в try-catch вызов метода, там где `await GetBids(...)`.

Comment: В методе `ProcessBidRequest` исключение перехватывается в `catch` и тут же снова бросается. Смысл этого? Не выбрасывайте его повторно.